# Backspace not working on whitespaces Oracle SQL Developer 20.4.1

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I recently downloaded the latest version of Oracle SQL Developer and am having a weird problem where the backspace does not remove the spaces to the left of any statement. Here is an example where I cannot remove the spaces before the words SELECT or FROM

[image: whitespaces]

PS. Already tried Tools - > Preferences - > Shortcut Keys -> More Actions -> Load keyboard schema -> Default, but didn't work, I think the reason is because backspace works in and on the right, but not on whitespaces to the left of any statement.

Comment: What's your keyboard layout?

Comment: This might be something to raise on [the SQL Developer forum](https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/categories/sql_developer)?